# How can I change configuration parameters of jQuery "easy pie chart" plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-easyui

I am using jQuery [easy pie chart plugin](http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/) for making pie charts. Initially I pass default configuration parameters. After that I want to change configuration parameters like `bar-color`, `size` of pie chart.

Default configuration parameters:

```
$('.chart').easyPieChart({
    easing: 'easeOutCirc',
    barColor: '#1abc9c  ',
    trackColor: '#f9f9f9  ',
    scaleColor:false,
    scaleLength: 5,
    percent: 67,
    lineCap: 'round',
    lineWidth: 15, //12
    size: 150, //110
    animate: {duration: 2000, enabled: true},
    onStep: function (from, to, percent) {
        $(this.el).find('.percent').text(Math.round(percent));
    }
});
```

I know how to set the `percentage` value of pie-chart dynamically, just like in the following way:

```
$('#'+domId).data('easyPieChart').update(value);
```

Except `percentage`, I want to set configuration parameters dynamically like:

I want to set `size`, `bar-color` of pie chart dynamically. For this I tried a lot of things but I didn't find the right way.

For this,I made [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yAv4f/112/) for understanding.Initially size should be `110` after click on `redraw` button needs to change the size of `pie chart`.But it's not working.

Tell me, does the plugin I am using fulfill my requirements? If it does, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

We must destroy the existing data and then recreate the graph

```
var $chart = $(".easy-pie-chart");
        $chart.data('easy-pie-chart', null);
        $chart.easyPieChart({
           // my new settings here
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that, as of now, the "easy pie chart" does not support dynamic options.

See https://github.com/rendro/easy-pie-chart/issues/65

If you want to stick with the plugin, you might want to recreate the chart completely on modifications (i.e. destroy the previous chart and create a new one).

Answer (score 0):

You can set these values for each chart on the page, for each id, not only for the class.

```
var chart = window.chart = $('#easypiechart1').data('easyPieChart');
$('.chart')#easyPieChart({
barColor: '#333',
}
```

});

Also, you can change these values from CSS.

```
.easypiechart {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Another option is to add an extra class on click (update).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to .remove .chart and to .append it again in the parent. For example:

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="chart-holder" data-count="86"><span class="chart" data-percent="86"></span></div>
```

JS:

```
$('.chart-holder').find('.chart').remove();
$('.chart-holder').append('<span class="chart" data-percent="'+ $('.chart-holder').attr('data-count') +'"></span>');
```

And after that:

```
$('.chart').easyPieChart({ .... });
```

It can be on click event or everything you want.

That's it. Simple solution.